# How to keep chaining Completable Futures?

Tags: java, completable-future

Have the following code:

```
public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {          
            NewMain nm =new  NewMain();
            nm.run(args);
        }
        catch (Exception  ex)
        {
            System.err.println( ex.getMessage() );
        }
    }
    
    public void run (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("testing async");
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        CompletableFuture<String> promise =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(sendPost, ex);
        promise.thenAccept(MuestraResultado);    
        System.out.println("done testing async");                
    }
   
Consumer<String> MuestraResultado = (String str) -> 
                                                                { 
                                                                    System.err.println( str.toUpperCase() );
                                                                };
        
 Supplier<String> sendPost  = ()-> {
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://myspace.co/app/a_method");
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        String data = "token=2dasdfe&id=1";

        byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
        stream.write(out);

        System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
        http.disconnect();
    }
    catch( IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    return "Done Post";
    };               
}
```

This code works perfect for me as it works asynchronously, console throws the following:

```
testing async
done testing async
200 200
DONE POST
```

However, I would like to keep chaining various async functions that depends from values obtained from the previous functions. Something like in javascript:

```
 function().then(function(res)
    {
        function_two(res).then(function(res_two))
            {
                function_three(res_two).then(function(res_three))
                        {
                            etc...
                        });        
            });
    });
```

But I dont seem to understand the underlying objects that works beneath CompletableFutures, since thenApply and ThenCompose doesnt espect suppliers...

**EDIT**

Just did the following...

```
    public void run (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("testing async");
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        CompletableFuture<String> promise =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(sendPost, ex);
        promise.thenApply((val)->
                                                {                                                    
                                                    return secondfunc(val);
                                                }).thenApply( (val) -> 
                                                                            {
                                                                                return thirdfunc(val);
                                                                            }).thenAccept(val->System.out.println(val));
        
        System.out.println("done testing async");                
    }
   
Consumer<String> MuestraResultado = (String str) -> 
                                                                { 
                                                                    System.err.println( str.toUpperCase() );
                                                                };
        
 Supplier<String> sendPost  = ()-> {
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://myspace.co/app/a_method");
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        String data = "token=2dasdfe&id_logins=1";

        byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
        stream.write(out);

        System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
        http.disconnect();
    }
    catch( IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    return "Done Post";
    };               
 
 String secondfunc(String secondStr)
 {
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://myspace.co/app/a_method");
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        String data = "token=2dasdfe&id_logins=1";

        byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
        stream.write(out);

        System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
        http.disconnect();
    }
    catch( IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    return secondStr.concat( "Done Post two" );
 }
 
  String thirdfunc(String thirdStr)
 {
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://myspace.co/app/a_method");
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        String data = "token=2dasdfe&id_logins=1";

        byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
        stream.write(out);

        System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
        http.disconnect();
    }
    catch( IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    return thirdStr.concat( "Done Post three" );
 }
```

And it worked... though I dont know if it is the best approach or practice...

Results:

```
testing async
done testing async
200 200
200 200
200 200
Done PostDone Post twoDone Post three
```

Comment: `CompletableFuture::thenApply`?

Comment: ThenApply Expects a function, is not like in the supplier lambda function that I could just pass it to de supplyAsync... or is it a way to wrap the a function without the supplier interface to make it return a completableFuture after the async stuff is done?

Comment: can you show a _simplified_ example of what you want to achieve and what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Sure, a minute.

Comment: Oh my god, this just worked, why in the world didnt I tried it first????...gonna post it...

Comment: Ok now I have another doubt. I will post it in a different question. Thank you man.

Comment: I know it's a bit off topic, but what is the value of posting `To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.` or `@author myself` as part of your question, or indeed, having it in your codebase? I realize your IDE inserts these things (you can tell it not to; the instructions for how to do that are *right there*), but you could at least edit it out before posting your question.

Comment: You are right, was in a rush. Did what you sugested :)